# Receving an attribute error for module in Lambda but not on local machine

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services

I am trying to retrieve an object from S3 using boto3 as follows:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    streaming_body = s3.Object(bucket_name=s3bucket,
                               key=documentPath
                               )

    body = {}
    body['filename'] = documentName
    body['file'] = streaming_body.get()['Body'].read()
```

This works fine on my local machine in PyCharm. However, when I upload to Lambda and make an API call, the following error is returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
'File "/var/task/s3getdocument.py", line 73, in lambda_handler
 body['file'] = streaming_body.get()['Body'].read()
 File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 648, in _make_api_call
operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 667, in _make_request
return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 135, in _send_request
request, operation_model, context)
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 167, in _get_response
request, operation_model)
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 218, in _do_get_response
response_dict, operation_model.output_shape)
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 242, in parse
parsed = self._do_parse(response, shape)
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 774, in _do_parse
member_shapes, final_parsed)
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 833, in _parse_non_payload_attrs
member_shape, headers[header_name])
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 302, in _parse_shape
return handler(shape, node)
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 175, in _get_text_content
return func(self, shape, text)
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 462, in _handle_timestamp
return self._timestamp_parser(text)
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/utils.py", line 567, in parse_timestamp
return dateutil.parser.parse(value, tzinfos={'GMT': tzutc()})
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py", line 1358, in parse
return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py", line 657, in parse
ret = self._build_tzaware(ret, res, tzinfos)
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py", line 1175, in _build_tzaware
aware = self._assign_tzname(aware, res.tzname)
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py", line 1238, in _assign_tzname
new_dt = tz.enfold(dt, fold=1)
AttributeError: module 'dateutil.tz' has no attribute 'enfold
```

All modules are the same versions in the lambda as they are on my local machine. I am using the latest version of boto3 and botocore as of today (5/30).

Any advise on what the difference might be that would cause this?

Comment: Does your code only fail on one particular object, or any object of any size?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Code fails, no matter what the object is. The code fails when running boto3 from a layer instead of using the runtime boto3

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly fine for me (on a small file):

```py
import boto3

s3bucket = 'my-bucket'
documentPath='foo.txt'

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    streaming_body = s3.Object(bucket_name=s3bucket,
                               key=documentPath
                               )

    body = {}
    body['filename'] = documentPath # Changed this
    body['file'] = streaming_body.get()['Body'].read()
    print(body['file'])
```

Comment: I was able to narrow the problem to using the latest version of  boto3 from a layer. When I run this code with a local import boto3 statement, Lambda runtime uses boto3 1.9.42 (latest is 1.9.158). If I attach the layer to working Lambda, the whole things breaks.  That being said, I still don't know why latest version of boto3 works locally on my machine, but not in Lambda runtime.

Comment: It could be that the layer has been badly constructed. (I haven't tried creating a boto3 layer, so can't offer any suggestions.) Are you doing it because you need to access a new feature?